Exactly what value does the Wilson line take?
Let $G$ be the Lie group of a given theory with the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$.
According to the Wikipedia article, a Wilson line is of the form
\begin{equation}
W[x_i,x_f]= P e^{i \int_{x_i}^{x_f} A}
\end{equation}
where $A$ is the $\mathfrak{g}$-valued connection.
Then, I guess that this Wilson line $W$ must be $G$-valued, but the path-ordering operator $P$ in front of the exponential seems like an issue...
Could anyone please confirm or correct my understanding?

Path ordering is just a prescription for the order in which the group elements are multiplied. Since a group is closed under multiplication, the path ordering does not pose any issue.

@Prahar The exponent consists of Lie "algebra" elements, whose "ordinary" exponential is supposed to yield an Lie "group" element. That is why I am confused.

Usually one takes trace so as to get a gauge invariant expression.  The result will  be a complex number.

@mikestone That is for the Wilson "loop", yes I agree. I am talking about Wilson "line", which is before taking the trace.

Then the line is a non-gauge-invariant  element of the gauge group in whatever representation the $A$'s live in.

@Keith - You break up the path $\gamma$ into infinitesimal segments of length $dx$. You define a Wilson line for each segment. The Wilson line on each segment is given by $e^{i d x ,t^\mu(x) A_\mu(x)}$ and is clearly group-valued ($t^\mu$ is the unit normalized tangent vector to $\gamma$ at the point $x$). The full Wilson line is then given by a path-ordered product over all the segments, followed by a limit $dx \to 0$. It should be clear from this that $W$ is group valued.

@mikestone yes, true.

@Prahar I see. Thank you for your clarification!
